# Moving GPS Points with a VB script - Bearing works well but distance is wrong

Tags: arcmap, coordinate-system, point, vb

I am using a script I found online created in 2003 by one of the commentators here.  It is a great script and exactly what I have been looking for and I'm very glad to have found it.  It simply takes a points file and using two fields in the table, bearing and distance it moves the points based on these two fields.  When I run it, the points always seem to move to the correct bearing but the distances are never correct.  For example, I may need to move a point 30 meters away from the original position at a bearing of 85 degrees.  The points move much more than that (hundreds of kilometers or more).  Is this a projection issue?  When I enter 30 in my table as my distance, do some projections interpret this as 30 degrees?  How do I get ArcMap to recognize that this is 30 meters?  If I can solve this I will be extremely happy.  My points file covers very large sections of geography covering many states.

The script is below

```
Option Explicit
Sub MovePoints()
    ' move points in layer(0) based on bearing and distance
    Dim pMxDoc As IMxDocument
    Set pMxDoc = ThisDocument
    
    Dim pFLayer As IFeatureLayer
    Set pFLayer = pMxDoc.FocusMap.Layer(0)
    
    Dim pFCur As IFeatureCursor
    Set pFCur = pFLayer.FeatureClass.Search(Nothing, False)
    
    Dim lBFld As Long, lDFld As Long
    lBFld = pFCur.FindField("Bearing")
    If lBFld = -1 Then
        MsgBox "bearing field not found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    lDFld = pFCur.FindField("Distance")
    If lDFld = -1 Then
        MsgBox "distance field not found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim pFeat As IFeature
    Set pFeat = pFCur.NextFeature
    Do Until pFeat Is Nothing
        Dim pConstPoint As IConstructPoint
        Set pConstPoint = New Point
        Dim dAngle As Double, dDist As Double, PI As Double
        PI = Atn(1#) * 4
        dAngle = Azi2Cart(pFeat.Value(lBFld)) * PI / 180
        dDist = pFeat.Value(lDFld)
        pConstPoint.ConstructAngleDistance pFeat.ShapeCopy, _
                                           dAngle, _
                                           dDist
        ' maybe set distance to 0 here
        ' to avoid moving it again
        'pFeat.Value(lDFld) = 0
        Set pFeat.Shape = pConstPoint
        pFeat.Store
        Set pFeat = pFCur.NextFeature
    Loop
    Dim pAV As IActiveView
    Set pAV = pMxDoc.FocusMap
    pAV.Refresh
End Sub

Function Azi2Cart(ByVal dCompassAngle As Double) As Double
    Azi2Cart = -dCompassAngle + 90
End Function
```

Comment: I'd have thought that the tables units was set to degree's. If you want to make sure you are working in a specific unit, either set the table to it, or find out what the table is using and then covert the amount you want to move, to that unit.